# Does Batman really love French onion soup?

Tags: dc, batman, dc-animated-universe, batman-the-animated-series

In "Vendetta", episode 23 of *Batman the Animated Series*, Alfred says to Batman: "I've made your favorite, **French onion soup**".

While this may just be a throw-away line, helping to lead into the "crock/croc" revelation Alfred and Batman share (it's the first Killer Croc episode), this scene made me wonder: **Is Batman's affinity/fondness/love for French onion soup mentioned elsewhere in canon?**

I will accept answers showing evidence that Alfred, or any member of the Wayne family, has made a mean bowl of French onion soup in the past, and could have swayed Bruce from an early age.

Comment: of course batman loves french onion soup, everyone loves french onion soup

Comment: Are the onions French, or the soup? Looking at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_onion_soup), a) probably the soup; b) the French just call it “onion soup”; and c) this may be my currently-mostly-Soylent diet talking, but it looks amazing.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - In the US, French Onion Soup is usually caramelized onions in beef and/or chicken stock with a touch of sherry.  It is put into a heat resistant crock.  A couple of croutons are floated on top, then covered with cheese, usually Gruyere.  The whole thing is placed under a broiler so the cheese gets melty and browned.

Comment: what's Batman's favorite soup? Alphabat soup.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**There are no other canon sources for Batman and his love of French onion soup.**

However, according to *Batman* Vol 1 #701 (2010) we find out that Batman's favorite food is mulligatawny soup, not French onion. This may imply that the writters do believe he loves soup, but cannot decide on the type.

> Alfred: Likewise, master Bruce. A tense few days, but I knew you'd work it out in the end. I prepared mulligatawny soup, your favorite.

[image: injured Alfred telling Batman he made soup]

For those wondering what exactly is mulligatawny soup, it is as follows:

> The original version of this soup consisted of a broth from chicken and lamb, fried onions and curry powder. Today it normally designates a thickened soup that is strongly spiced with curry powder and nutmeg. Often, strips of vegetables, nuts and rice are added, sometimes also port wine.
>     <sub>[-- Wikipedia - Mulligatawny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mulligatawny)</sub>

[image: bowl of soup and spoon]

Comment: Dude, you're the man.

Comment: fried onions ~ french onions, seems like he likes onion soup regardless of extras.

Comment: I guess when you're rich, you can put wine in anything.

Comment: The original recipe for mulligatawny soup sounds way better than the current one.

Comment: Also, in *Justice League: Doom*, Alfred makes Bruce chicken soup, presumably because he's injured and weary, not because it's his favorite. Another soup reference though. Strange.

Comment: What is with Batman and soup? Batman Returns features a funny gag where Alfred brings a bowl of soup to Bruce, who begins to slurp absent-mindedly, only to spit it out and proclaim "It's cold!". Alfred retorts "It's Vichyssoise, sir.", and adds, after receiving a blank look from Bruce "It's supposed to be cold." Bruce shrugs, and then digs in. Wikipedia states that Vichyssoise "a thick soup made of boiled and puréed leeks, onions, potatoes, cream, and chicken stock." so, we can now definitively ascertain that Bruce likes soup with onions in it.

Comment: Why can't a man's tastes change?  Why does he have to have just one favorite?

Comment: @Paul: For a man who ages a few years over the course of over sixty? :-D Superheroes are somewhat static by nature.

Comment: @Paul: Batman thought he had a contingency for everything, until he tasted mulligatawny soup.